# What is the concept of Array.map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, mozilla, array-map

I am having problems understanding the concept of `Array.map`. I did go to Mozilla and Tutorials Point, but they provided very limited info regarding this.

This is how I am using `Array.map`. It is a little complex (a bit of d3.js involved; just ignore it)

```
var mapCell = function (row) {
    return columns.map(function(column) {
        return { column : column, value : getColumnCell(row, column) }
    })
}
//getColumnCell is a function defined in my code
//columns is array defined at the top of my code
```

I do not understand exactly what this code is doing. I know its returning a new array and stuff but this part is a little tricky!

If you want to go through my code: http://jsfiddle.net/ddfsb/2/

I am using console to actually understand what's happening inside the code. Looking at the answers provided, I have clearly understood the concept of `array.map`. Now the only part remaining is parameters rows and columns, but there is a difference between row and rows, and column and columns in the fiddle provided

```
var rows//completely ok
var columns//completely ok
funcion(row)//here,source of row is unknown.getColumncell function utilizes this parameter further making it more critical
function(column)//source of column is unknown..getColumncell function utilizes this parameter further making it more critical
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Let's rewrite it a bit, and start working from inside out.

```
var mapCell = function (row) {
  return columns.map(
    function(column) {
      return { 
        column : column, 
        value : getColumnCell(row, column)
      }
    }
  )
}
```

The `function(column)` part is essentially a function that takes a column as a parameter, and returns a new object with two properties:

- column, that is the original value of the parameter, and
- value, that is the result of calling the getColumnCell function on the row (external variable) and column (parameter)

The `columns.map()` part calls the [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function, that takes an array and a function, and runs the function for every last item of it, and returns the results. i.e. if the input is the array `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and the function is something like `isEven`, the result will be the array `[false, true, false, true, false]`. In your case, the input are the columns, and the output is a list of objects, each of which has a column and a value properties.

Lastly, the `var mapCell = function (row)` part declares that the variable `mapCell` will contain a function of one variable called `row` - and this is the same `row` that is used in the inner function.

In a single sentence, this line of code, declares a function that when run, will take a row and return values for all columns for that row.

Comment: can i know where is this column parameter and the row parameter coming from,the thing is i just dumped this code from a website without understanding and now i am suffering..

Comment: The assumption in this code is that the `row` parameter is passed to the function, that `columns` is a collection of things called `column`, and that there exists a function called `getColumnCell` that takes a row and a column as parameters. From this snippet only, it's impossible to say what they are or where those things come from.

Answer (score 3):

`map` loops through your original array and calls the method for each value in the array.  It collects the results of your function to create a new array with the results.  You are "mapping" the array of values into a new array of mapped values.  Your code is equivalent to:

```
var mapCell = function (row) {
    var result = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; ++i) {
            var mappedValue = {
                column: columns[i], 
                value : getColumnCell(row, columns[i])
            };
            result.push(mappedValue);
        }
    return result;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Understanding the map function is only part of the solution here, there is also the function `mapCell`. It takes one parameter `row` and it returns something like:

```
[ {
    "column": "parties",
    "value": [cell value]
}, {
    "column": "star-speak",
    "value": [cell value]
} ]
```

Where the cell value depends on the `row` and the column (parties, stars-speak etc.)

A map function applies a transformation to a value, and returns that transformed value.

A simple example:

```
function square(x) { return x * x; }

[ 2, 3, 4 ].map(square); // gives: [ 4, 9, 16 ]
```

Similarly:

```
[ "parties", "starspeak" ].map(function (column) {
    return {
        column: column,
        value: findTheValue(column)
    }
});
```

Now since that map is nested with a function that gets a `row` parameter. You can use it in the map function, to get:

```
function (row) {
    return [ "parties", "starspeak" ].map(function (column) {
        return {
            column: column,
            value: findTheValue(row, column)
        }
    });
}
```

And this gets pretty close to your code.

Comment: i dint understood the function(row) and .map(function (column){}....
these parameters inside the function causing me problem.

where are these parameters coming from

Comment: where are these parameter row and column coming from??

Comment: `column` are the elements of `columns`, so `"parties"`, `"starspeak"` etc. `row` is passed in as an argument from elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Map function goes through each element of an array in ascending order and invokes function f on all of them.
It returns new array which is being computed after function is invoked on it.

Syntax: 
`array.map(f)`

Example:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
 <script>
   var arr = [4,5,6];
   document.write(arr.map(function(x){return x*2;}));
 </script>
 </head>
</html>
```

Answer: 8,10,12

Answer (score 2):

### Summary

`Array.map` is a function which is located on `Array.prototype.map`. The function does the following:

1. Creates **a new array** with the same amount of entries/elements.
2. Executes a callback function, this function receives and current array element as an argument and returns the entry for the new array.
3. Returns the newly created array.

### Example:

**Basic usage:**

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4];

// receive each element of array then multiply it times two
// map returns a new array
const map = array.map(x => x * 2);

console.log(map);
```

**The callback function also exposes an index and the original array:**

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4];

// the callback function can also receive the index and the 
// original array on which map was called upon
const map = array.map((x, index, array) => {
  console.log(index);
  console.log(array);
  return x + index;
});

console.log(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably most people coming here (like me) just want a basic `array.map` usage example:

```
myArray = [1,2,3]
mappedArray = [];

mappedArray = myArray.map(function(currentValue){
     return currentValue *= 2;
})

//myArray is still [1,2,3]
//mappedArray is now [2,4,6]
```

This is it at it's most basic. For additional parameers, check out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 0):

IF you have an array of elements and you have to perform the same operation on the
each element of the array that time you can use the javascript map function for array
it helps to iterate throw the array then we can perform the operation of each element and 
return it.

```
let NumberArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];

let UpdatedArray = NumberArray.map( (Num , index )=>{ 
                return Num*10;
            })

console.log(UpdatedArray);

//UpdatedArray ==> [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript map() Syntax**

arrayObj.map(callback[,context]);

arrayObj is a original array on which map() is invoked.

The map() takes 2 named arguments, First is a callback function and the second is a context object. callback function gets triggered on every element of an array.

In addition, callback function takes 3 arguments:

function callback(currentElement,index,array){

}

currentElement – This is a current elements of array which is passed to callback function

index – Index of the current element

array – complete array on which map() is applied

Out of these 3 elements, currentElement parameter is mandatory while the rest 2 parameters are optional.

However, map() does not change the original array, it creates a new array element which is generated by callback function.

You can read more on [JavaScript map function](https://codetopology.com/scripts/javascript-tutorials/javascript-map-function)

Answer (score 0):

Array map() method returns a new array.
It does not change the original array.

`let array = arr.map((c, i, arr) => { //return element to new array });`

here,

- array is the new array that is returned.
- arr is the original array on which the map method is called.
- c is the current value that is being processed.
- i is the index of current value.

For example:-

`const originalArr = [4, 3, 2]; let newArr = originalArr.map((val) => val + val);`

result:-

newArr: [8, 6, 4]
originalArr: [4, 3, 2]

Answer (score 0):

in simple words you can perform operations on array using map

Examples
**1.Array**

```js
let arr = ["sam","tom"]

console.log("Before map :",arr)
arr.map((d,i)=>{
    arr[i] = d+"yy"
})

  console.log("After map  :",arr)
```

Examples
**2.Array Of Objects**

```js
// console.log(Date.now());

let arr = [
  {name:"sam",roll_no:10},
  {name:"tom",roll_no:12}
]
  
  console.log("Before map :",arr)
  
arr.map(d=>{
  if(d.name == "sam")
  {
      d.name = "sammy",
      d.roll_no=100
  }
})

  console.log("After map :",arr)
```