# Get count and values of checkbox on click of it in the textbox and on uncheck the value should be removed and count should decreased in textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

below is the html code 
i would like to get the values of checkboxes seperated with comma in the textbox of id='selchk' and get the count of checkbox clicked in textbox of id='getcnt' and on uncheck the value should be removed and count should be reduced using jquery.i have tried but didn't achieve the result.need help

```
<input type='checkbox' class='chk' value='1'>        
<input type='checkbox' class='chk' value='2'>       
<input type='checkbox' class='chk' value='3'>        
<input type='checkbox' class='chk' value='4'>        
<input type='checkbox' class='chk' value='5'>        
<input type='checkbox' class='chk' value='6'>           
<input type='text' class='getcnt' id='getcnt'>        
<input type='text' class='selchk' id='selchk'>
```

Comment: question is not up to the mark... what is "get the count of valuess" ???

Comment: total no of values in the textbox which are clicked by the user

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/parthi04/rcfjuk1t/ check ..whether i got your points?

Comment: no i want the values of checkbox in textbox(selchk) with comma seperated and on uncheck the values should be removed and the count means how much checkbox are selected in the textbox and count should reduce on uncheck and the value should be removed

Comment: What have you tried yet post your jsfiddle code link here let us see what you have done so far first ? @curious2lrn

Comment: @curious2lrn http://jsfiddle.net/parthi04/rcfjuk1t/1/ @ check this now

Comment: @surajrawat http://jsfiddle.net/curious2lrn/fau16hyy/ this is the jsfiddle code i don't know much of  jquery just tried no result

Comment: @Parthi04 what is the use of i in function(n,i)

Comment: @Parthi04 thats correct just trying to understand the concept. can you explain?

Comment: This is join method http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp
Array Map :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17367889/array-map-concept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/parthi04/rcfjuk1t/1/)
>
> var total = 0;
>
> $(".chk").click(function(){
>
> ```
>   var output = $.map($('.chk:checked'), function(n, i){
>     return n.value;
>   }).join(',');
>
>   total = $('.chk:checked').length;
>   $("#getcnt").val(total);
>   $("#selchk").val(output);
> });
> ```
>
> [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/parthi04/rcfjuk1t/1/)

Comment: Nice use of the $.map();

Comment: @Parthi04 my reputation is 1 can i mark it as an correct answer.if yes then how to mark it?

Comment: @curious2lrn you will have a "Tick" mark below the  upvote & downvote buton in my answer

Answer (score 1):

[CodePen Example](http://codepen.io/node/pen/qEOaEa)

```
var $boxes = $('input[type=checkbox]'),
    $count = $('#getcnt'),
    $values = $('#selchk');

$boxes.click(function() {
    var values = [];
    var checked =0;
    $boxes.each(function() {
      if (this.checked) {
        values.push(this.value);
        checked++;
      }
    });
    $count.attr('value',checked);
    $values.attr('value',values.toString());
});
```