# Converting JavaScript Array To Array With a Property

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have an array like this coming back response from the server:

```
[
    "111",
    "1010",
    "111",
    "1010",
    "1010"
]
```

i want to convert it into a JavaScript JSON like this:

```
[
 {
    "branch":  "111"

 },
 {
    "branch":  "1010"
 },
 {
    "branch":  "111"
 },
 {
    "branch":  "1010"
 },
 {
    "branch":  "1010"
 }
]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the concept of Array.map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17367889/what-is-the-concept-of-array-map)

Comment: thats not a valid json.. -> check colons before `}` - I edited your question..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could map a short hand property.

```js
var array = ["111", "1010", "111", "1010", "1010"],
    result = array.map(branch => ({ branch }));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array

```js
var arr = [
    "111",
    "1010",
    "111",
    "1010",
    "1010"
]

var res = arr.map(i => ({'branch': i}));
console.log(res);
```