# show and hide display with same class using javascript

Tags: javascript

i am trying to choose which element to show and hide using javascript, i can't make change on html, the below javascript show error on "Cannot set property 'display' of undefined". How can i show and hide element which share same class?

```
var showHideBrandPic = document.querySelectorAll("h1.plp_brand_title");
var pic = document.querySelectorAll('.hero_discription_container_left');


function showHidePic (){
    showHideBrandPic.forEach(showHideBrandPic => {
        if(showHideBrandPic.textContent === "ADIDAS BY PHARRELL WILLIAMS"){
            pic.style.display = "none";
        }else {
            pic.style.display = "block";
        }
    })
   
};

showHidePic();
```

```
<h1 class="plp_brand_title">abc</h1>
    <img class="hero_discription_container_left" src="/qw.png" alt="123" width="500" height="600">
<h1 class="plp_brand_title">ADIDAS BY PHARRELL WILLIAMS</h1>
    <img class="hero_discription_container_left" src="/qw.png" alt="123" width="500" height="600">
```

Comment: `pic.style` should be `showHideBrandPic.style` - where did `pic` come from?

Comment: because i want to hide the image instead of the <h1>, but i don't know how to do it. The only thing i can define it need to show or hide is h1 textContent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This adds a layer of functionality allowing you to set an array of text to find and hide the image after.

This method relies on that there will always be an image with class `.hero_discription_container_left` that follows an h1 with class that is in the classnames array. You get both in an array so it's easy to associate them.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  let removeImagesAfter = ["remove my image too", "remove ME", "ADIDAS BY PHARRELL WILLIAMS"].map(e => e.toLowerCase()); // for sake of comparisons, we convert these to lower case 
  const classNames = ["plp_brand_title", "otherclass", "otherclass2"]
  let h1s = document.querySelectorAll("h1")
  let imgs = document.querySelectorAll("img.hero_discription_container_left")
  h1s.forEach((h1, i) => {
    if (classNames.filter(c => h1.classList.contains(c)).length === 0) return;
    imgs[i].style.display = removeImagesAfter.includes(h1.innerText.trim().toLowerCase()) ? 'none' : 'block';
  })
})
```

```html
<h1 class="otherclass2">remove my image too</h1>
<img class="hero_discription_container_left" src="/qw.png" alt="123" width="500" height="6">
<h1 class="plp_brand_title">abc</h1>
<img class="hero_discription_container_left" src="/qw.png" alt="123" width="500" height="6">
<h1 class="plp_brand_title">ADIDAS BY PHARRELL WILLIAMS</h1>
<img class="hero_discription_container_left" src="/qw.png" alt="123" width="500" height="6">
<h1 class="someotherclass">Not me</h1>
<img class="hero_discription_container_left" src="/qw.png" alt="123" width="500" height="6">
<h1 class="otherclass">remove me</h1>
<img class="hero_discription_container_left" src="/qw.png" alt="123" width="500" height="6">
```

Here's another method using `element.nextElementSibling` which allows us to iterate through the elements one after the other.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  let removeImagesAfter = ["ADIDAS BY PHARRELL WILLIAMS"].map(e=>e.toLowerCase()); // for sake of comparisons, we convert these to lower case 
  document.querySelectorAll("h1.plp_brand_title").forEach(h1 => {
    if (removeImagesAfter.includes(h1.innerText.trim().toLowerCase())) {
      let sibling = h1.nextElementSibling
      while (sibling && sibling.tagName !== 'IMG') {
        sibling = sibling.nextElementSibling
      }
      sibling.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      h1.nextElementSibling.style.display = "block";
    }
  })

})
```

```html
<h1 class="plp_brand_title">abc</h1>
<img class="hero_discription_container_left" src="/qw.png" alt="123" width="500" height="6">
<h1 class="plp_brand_title">ADIDAS BY PHARRELL WILLIAMS</h1>
<img class="hero_discription_container_left" src="/qw.png" alt="123" width="500" height="6">
```

Comment: What if there is more images after different h1 need to be remove?

Comment: is it all h1's or only certain classes? What are the h1 classes?

Comment: only certain classes.

Comment: because there is multiple html file who is sharing with master js file, so i need to hide or show multiple image after same class h1 at the same time

Comment: even they are sharing same class, but there textContent are different

Comment: I updated my answer to include an array of classNames to search for

Answer (score 0):

**querySelectorAll** targets all elements, you need to then specify which index you want affected.

*example: use **pic[0].style** or **pic[1].style** instead of **pic.style***

```js
var showHideBrandPic = document.querySelectorAll("h1.plp_brand_title");
var pic = document.querySelectorAll('.hero_discription_container_left');


function showHidePic (){
    showHideBrandPic.forEach((showHideBrandPic, i) => {
        if(showHideBrandPic.textContent === "ADIDAS BY PHARRELL WILLIAMS"){
            pic[i].style.display = "none";
        }else {
            pic[i].style.display = "block";
        }
    })
   
}

showHidePic();
```

```html
<h1 class="plp_brand_title">abc</h1>
    <img class="hero_discription_container_left" src="/qw.png" alt="123" width="500" height="600">
<h1 class="plp_brand_title">ADIDAS BY PHARRELL WILLIAMS</h1>
    <img class="hero_discription_container_left" src="/qw.png" alt="123" width="500" height="600">
```

If you want all the elements affected, either loop through or use JavaScript's built-in **maps**:
[What is the concept of Array.map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17367889/what-is-the-concept-of-array-map)

Answer (score 0):

The following will scan your markup for titles and images following a certain title and puts the results in the array `els`. There can be any number (including 0) of images in a section started by a title, provided the image has the given class `hero_discription_container_left`. `els` is then an array of arrays. Each sub-array will contain as a first value the `style.display` value that is to be applied on all following `<img>` elements in the same sub-array. In an inner `forEach()` loop these display values are then assigned to the individual `<img>` elements (`im`).

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  const brands = ["ADIDAS BY PHARRELL WILLIAMS"];
  const els=[];
  document.querySelectorAll("h1.plp_brand_title,img.hero_discription_container_left").forEach(el =>{
    if (el.tagName==="H1") els.push([brands.includes(el.innerText)?"none":"block"]);
    else els[els.length-1].push(el);
  });
  els.forEach(([disp,...imgs])=>
    imgs.forEach(im=>im.style.display=disp)
  )
})
```

```html
<h1 class="plp_brand_title">abc</h1>
<img class="hero_discription_container_left" src="/qw.png" alt="123" width="500" height="6">
<h1 class="plp_brand_title">ADIDAS BY PHARRELL WILLIAMS</h1>
<img class="hero_discription_container_left" src="/qw.png" alt="123" width="500" height="6">
```