# Filter output from an array

Tags: arrays, json, sorting, postman

I'm completely new to postman. I'm able to GET the following results below.

How would I go about defining my output from the array.
So for example, the call output should only list the Real_name,Title and emailaddress fields?

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "offset": "DDGGDFRDFG",
    "members": [
        {
            "id": "100",
            "real_name": "First Surname",
            "tz": "Europe/London",
            "profile": {
                "title": "Sales",
                ],
                "email": "First.Surname@test.com",
            },
            "is_admin": False,
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "101",
            "real_name": "First1 Surname1",
            "tz": "Europe/London",
            "profile": {
                "title": "Acccounts",
                ],
                "email": "First1.Surname1@test.com",
            },
            "is_admin": False,
                ]
            }
        },
```

Comment: It depends on server api code, not come from client.

Comment: First of all, your JSON (besides being incompete) is also invalid ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the concept of Array.map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17367889/what-is-the-concept-of-array-map)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a post processing java-script in `Tests` of Postman.

It can [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) or [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) operation of JSON array.

Your JSON out is not validate, I changed a bits

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "offset": "DDGGDFRDFG",
    "members": [
        {
            "id": "100",
            "real_name": "First Surname",
            "tz": "Europe/London",
            "profile": {
                "title": "Sales",
                "email": "First.Surname@test.com"
            },
            "is_admin": false
        },
        {
            "id": "101",
            "real_name": "First1 Surname1",
            "tz": "Europe/London",
            "profile": {
                "title": "Acccounts",
                "email": "First1.Surname1@test.com"
            },
            "is_admin": false
        }
    ]
}
```

I think you want to shows only this JSON

```
[
  {
    "real_name": "First Surname",
    "title": "Sales",
    "email": "First.Surname@test.com"
  },
  {
    "real_name": "First1 Surname1",
    "title": "Acccounts",
    "email": "First1.Surname1@test.com"
  }
]
```

This Javascript will makes result. You needs to put in `Tests` tab section.

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
var real_names = jsonData.members
    .map (el => {
        return {
            real_name : el.real_name,
            title : el.profile.title,
            email : el.profile.email
        }
    });
console.log(JSON.stringify(real_names, null, 4))
```

Test by Postman,

[image]

line 1 : var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
API response to makes JSON format and save into `jsonData` variable

line 2~9 : `jsonData.members` is array data type due to start `[` to end `]`
Then using `map` function with just pick-up `real_name`, `title` and `email`.

line 10: return object array from map, convert JSON format and indent with 4 spaces. console.log() will print to `Console` of postman.

[image]