# Transfor the Array to another format in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the code like this one below, woluld like to convert to another format

```js
 result :  [
  { _id: 'Completed', count: 1 },
  { _id: 'Assigned', count: 9 },
  { _id: 'Closed', count: 2 },
  { _id: 'In-Progress', count: 5 }
]
```

I want the format as below

```js
 result :  [
  { Completed :1 },
  { Assigned, : 9 },
  { Closed,: 2 },
  { In-Progress : 5 }
]
```

Thanks

Comment: Hey Syed, if you want us to help, could you give some more background info, please? Like what language this is? What data structures you are using, etc? Otherwise, there is a high chance this question was already answered, so look for that too.

Comment: sorry, in javascript, i have edited my question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17367889/what-is-the-concept-of-array-map

Comment: Sorry, my idea was like 

 result =   
  { Completed :1 , 
    Assigned, : 9 , 
    Closed: 2,
    In-Progress : 5 
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `map()`

```js
const result =  [
  { _id: 'Completed', count: 1 },
  { _id: 'Assigned', count: 9 },
  { _id: 'Closed', count: 2 },
  { _id: 'In-Progress', count: 5 }
]

const formattedArray = result.map((item, index) => {
   return { [item._id]: item.count }
})

console.log(formattedArray)
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, Its works fine, i was trying to use 'for of'
 for (const object of result) {
    arr.push({  [object._id]: object.count} );
 }

Comment: I found thesolution 


var result =  [
  { _id: 'Completed', count: 21 },
  { _id: 'Assigned', count: 91 },
  { _id: 'Closed', count: 22 },
  { _id: 'In-Progress', count: 25 }
]

let obj ={}
 for (const object of result) {
   obj[object._id] = object.count   
 }

Thanks