# How to replace elements from array with another element

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a JSON array of objects out of which I need to create an Object of countries and continents like below:

For ex-

```
{
 "Asia":['India','China'],
 "Europe": ['Germany','United Kingdom']
}
```

So basically in above object continents would be a key and all the countries corresponding to that continent would come into array as a value.

This is what I want-

1. `Unite Kingdom` should replace with `UK` inside an object.

Below is my code but its giving a wrong output:

```
   const arr = [
         {
            'id':1,
            'geography':'region',
            'zone':'Europe',
            'countries':['United Kingdom','France','Germany']
         },
         {
            'id':1,
            'geography':'global',
            'zone':'global',
         },
         {
            'id':1,
            'geography':'region',
            'zone':'Europe',
            'countries':['France','Germany','Netherlands']
         }
        ];
        
const obj = {};

for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
 //Check if geography is region only
 if(arr[i].geography === 'region') {
    //Checking if property is already exists in object
    if(obj[arr[i].zone]) {
        obj[arr[i].countries].map((items) => {
           obj[arr[i].zone].push(items);     
        });
    }
    //If property is not there then insert
    else{
        obj[arr[i].zone] = obj[arr[i].countries];
    }
  }
}  

console.log(obj);
```

Its giving me below output:

```
{ Europe: undefined }
```

Someone let me know what I am doing wrong in above code.

Comment: `obj[arr[i].zone] = obj[arr[i].countries];` - for starters, I think you want to assign `arr[i].countries` here, and not `obj[arr[i].countries]`

Comment: And `obj[arr[i].countries].map()` should be `arr[i].countries.map()`.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173)

Comment: Please do not use `.map()` for simple array iteration. Use `.forEach()` or a normal loop to do that. See: [Is performing a mapping operation without using returned value an antipattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56903693) | [Is performing a mapping operation without using returned value an antipattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56903693) | [Is there a difference between foreach and map?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/354909) | [What is the concept of Array.map?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17367889)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are trying to access the property of `obj` using the value of `arr[i].countries`, which is an array. You should instead use the *key* countries to get the array of countries, and then loop over it to add each country to the corresponding continent in the `obj`.

Also, to replace "United Kingdom" with "UK", you can use the replace method of the String object.

Try the following:

```js
const arr = [
         {
            'id':1,
            'geography':'region',
            'zone':'Europe',
            'countries':['United Kingdom','France','Germany']
         },
         {
            'id':1,
            'geography':'global',
            'zone':'global',
         },
         {
            'id':1,
            'geography':'region',
            'zone':'Europe',
            'countries':['France','Germany','Netherlands']
         }
        ];

const obj = {};

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i].geography === 'region') {
    if (obj[arr[i].zone]) {
      for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].countries.length; j++) {
        let temp = arr[i].countries[j].includes(' ')? arr[i].countries[j].match(/\b\w/g).join('').toUpperCase() : arr[i].countries[j];
        obj[arr[i].zone].push(temp);
      }
    } else {
      obj[arr[i].zone] = [];
      for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].countries.length; j++) {
        let temp = arr[i].countries[j].includes(' ')? arr[i].countries[j].match(/\b\w/g).join('').toUpperCase() : arr[i].countries[j];
        obj[arr[i].zone].push(temp);
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: What about let's say if I have `United States` I want to replace it with `US` instead so can I do that in the same replace statement.