# Remove Li Element in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have code below which I'm intended to remove the li element inside of ul element in typescript

```
deleteAll?.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const ul = document.getElementsByTagName("ul");
  ul.innerHTML = ""
})
```

However, the ul.innerHTML give an error of "Property 'innerHTML' does not exist on type 'HTMLCollectionOf'" is there any step that I missed here? or I should define the type in variable ul?

Answer (score -1):

`document.getElementsByTagName("ul")` returns a HTMLCollection (a list of Nodes), you need to turn it into an array, iterate through those `ul`s in the array.

```
deleteAll?.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const ulEls = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('ul'));
  
  ulEls.forEach(ul => {
    ul.innerHTML = '';
  });
});

})
```

Comment: Please do not use `.map()` for simple array iteration. Use `.forEach()` or a normal loop to do that. See: [Is performing a mapping operation without using returned value an antipattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56903693) | [Is performing a mapping operation without using returned value an antipattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56903693) | [Is there a difference between foreach and map?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/354909) | [What is the concept of Array.map?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17367889)

Comment: Interesting, although I couldn't find any info on the singular `getElementByTagName` function?

Comment: @Harrison that's because no such method exists.

Comment: Ah I thought so

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I updated my answer to use `forEach` for better performance and I removed the `getElementByTagName` as there is indeed no such DOM method.